# Using relative url for git submodule needs credentials

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-submodules, azure-pipelines

The Team Services documentation (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/repository#what-kinds-of-submodules-can-i-check-out) points out that I can do a `$ git add submodule` if

- it is an immediate submodule
- Unauthenticated (n/a)
- Authenticated

  - Contained in the same team project
  - Added by using a relative url from main repository

They give an example:

```
git submodule add /../../submodule.git mymodule
```

If I reference a git repo in the same project like

```
git submodule add ./../other-repo mymodule
```

It resolves the right repo but wants me to provide credentials. The build fails with the following message:

```
Cloning into 'mymodule'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://xxx.visualstudio.com': Invalid argument
```

Providing the full URL with credentials (https://user:password@xxx.visualstudio.com/...) works but is IMO a bad solution.

The documentation suggests that this should work with a relative url and without credentials. Am I wrong?

### Edit 1:

Running with system.debug: true

```
Entering OnPrepareEnvironment
Primary repository: xxx
Calculating build folder hash key.
Loading tracking config if exists: C:\a\SourceRootMapping\07a8b96d-d805-4646-83d3-e7b2fbe394c2\18\SourceFolder.json
Creating new tracking config.
Loading top-level tracking config if exists: C:\a\SourceRootMapping\Mappings.json
Writing config to file: C:\a\SourceRootMapping\Mappings.json
Writing config to file: C:\a\SourceRootMapping\07a8b96d-d805-4646-83d3-e7b2fbe394c2\18\SourceFolder.json
Checking if artifacts directory exists: C:\a\1\a
Creating artifacts directory.
Checking if test results directory exists: C:\a\1\TestResults
Creating test results directory.
Creating binaries directory.
Setting local variables.
Create the initial timeline records for the tasks
Preparing repositories
repo clean = False
Found 3 endpoints to consider
Found 1 repositories to sync
Starting: Get sources
build.fetchtags=false
Entering GitSourceProvider.PrepareRepositoryAsync
Repository type=TfsGit
localPath=C:\a\1\s
clean=False
sourceBranch=refs/heads/r_080
sourceVersion=26d5a7a6e6ed47c8f12ee5dc5b376d6731b7863a
Syncing repository: xxx (Git)
repository url=https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_git/xxx
checkoutSubmodules=False
Starting clone
Checking out 26d5a7a6e6ed47c8f12ee5dc5b376d6731b7863a to C:\a\1\s
Checked out branch refs/heads/r_080 for repository xxx at commit 26d5a7a6e6ed47c8f12ee5dc5b376d6731b7863a
Leaving GitSourceProvider.PrepareRepositoryAsync
Leaving OnPrepareEnvironment
Running tasks
Starting task: Run git
##[warning]File name doesn't indicate a full path to a executable file.
Executing the following command-line. (workingFolder = C:\a\1\s)
git submodule add ./../other_repo mymodule
Error message highlight pattern: 
Warning message highlight pattern: 
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "git submodule add ./../other_repo mymodule"
Cloning into 'mymodule'...
Fatal: InvalidOperationException encountered.
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://xxx.visualstudio.com': Invalid argument
fatal: clone of 'https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_git/other_repo' into submodule path 'mymodule' failed
Finishing task: CmdLine
##[error]System.Exception: Task CmdLine failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.Run(IJobContext jobContext, IJobRequest job, IJobExtension jobExtension, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
Entering OnFinalizeJob
Leaving OnFinalizeJob
```

## Edit 2:

I cannot answer this. The documentation is wrong/unclear, I went with the option to check out submodules like @eddie-msft said - but watch out: [VSTS git build fails with git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752629/vsts-git-build-fails-with-git-submodule/)

Comment: I tried with you command to add a Git Submodule and queue a build but didn't see any issue. Can you queue the build with "system.debug" variable set to "true" and then share the entire logs?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT added as Edit

Comment: According to the logs, you are adding the submodule repo during a build process via "Command Line" build tasks. Can you try adding the submodule on your local machine and then pushing the changes? Please also try with "git submodule add ../other-repo mymodule" command.

Comment: I added it locally and tried to "git submodule update --init" in a build-step but that did just nothing. Using ../other-repo mymodule fails with the same error message.

Comment: You don't need to get it in build step namually, just check "checkout submodule" option in the build definition repository settings.

Comment: Well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752629/vsts-git-build-fails-with-git-submodule/

Comment: It's a different behavior, in this case, the command line task does not have the credential information for authentication, you need to do this via "checkout submodules" option. And I added another point you need to pay attention if you use relative path.

Comment: See my related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63593883/791706, about reusing the main repo credentials for submodules in the same organization.

Answer (score 5):

I understand from the [Submodules - Azure Repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#submodules) that there are issues when:

- Submodule repo requires authentication.
- You have enabled [Limit job authorization scope to referenced Azure DevOps repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#limit-job-authorization-scope-to-referenced-azure-devops-repositories), which is enabled by default.

> If you restricted the job access token as explained in the section above, then you won't be able to do this.

I have only tried nr 1 myself and it works for us.

### Workaround 1: For submodule repo in DevOps

- Disable `Limit job authorization scope to referenced Azure DevOps repositories` in project settings, which grants the pipeline access to all DevOps repositories.
- [Use relative paths instead of https:// in the submodule URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#submodules), such as `../MySubmoduleRepo` or `../../../OtherProject/_git/MySubmoduleRepo`.

### Workaround 2: If different credentials are needed

- [Use a script to checkout with a personal access token (PAT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#alternative-to-using-the-checkout-submodules-option)

### Workaround 3: Custom script to reuse access token for submodule sync

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63593883/134761

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  submodules: false
  persistCredentials : true

- powershell: |
    $header = "AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)"
    git -c http.extraheader="$header" submodule sync
    git -c http.extraheader="$header" submodule update --init --force --depth=1
```

Comment: Using relative path fixed it for my azure pipeline! Thank you

Comment: Workaround 3 worked for me instantly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please also check the path of your two repositories. If you have only two repositories in your project, the path of the first created repo A would be:

```
https://xxxx.visualstudio.com/_git/A
```

And the path of the second created repo B would be:

```
https://xxxx.visualstudio.com/A/_git/B
```

In this scenario, you need to use a relative path like following:

```
../../A/_git/B
```