# Git Submodule update on pipelines with hosted agent

Tags: azure-devops, git-submodules, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have a self hosted agent and have a git repository with submodules. URLs in .gitmodules are `http://`

When I try to initialize a job it fails to update submodules.

```
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init --force
Cloning into 'foo-dev-common'...
Submodule 'foo-dev-common' (https://MY_ORG@dev.azure.com/MY_ORG/PInC/_git/foo-dev-common) registered for path 'foo-dev-common'
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://MY_ORG@dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled
fatal: clone of 'https://MY_ORG@dev.azure.com/MY_ORG/PInC/_git/foo-dev-common' into submodule path 'foo-dev-common' failed
##[error]Git submodule update failed with exit code: 128
Finishing: Checkout foo-rose-identity-service@submod_bd_mahesh to s/foo-rose-identity-service
```

I have also tried adding repository self and

```
    steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true
    persistCredentials: true
```

Answer (score 7):

forvaidya's answer didn't work for me (though it is now 4 years later).
(Relative URLs in `.gitmodules` are resolved to full URLs in `.git/config` by `git submodule sync`.)

`persistCredentials: true` will keep the authorization header available in `git config` for future steps, but it is keyed by your main repo URL.  As long as the submodule repo(s) are in the same organization, you can reuse the header, though - e.g. in a pipeline Powershell script:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  submodules: false
  persistCredentials : true

- powershell: |
    $header = $(git config --get-all http.$(Build.Repository.Uri).extraheader)
    git -c http.extraheader="$header" submodule sync
    git -c http.extraheader="$header" submodule update --init --force --depth=1
```

(I gleaned these details from the logs of the standard `checkout` step.  Note the reference to the `Build.Repository.Uri` pipeline variable.)

The above will accomplish a full ("unshallow") checkout of the main repo (useful for e.g. [GitVersion](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion)), without submodules, and a shallow checkout of any submodules.

Edit: The [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken) way to get the authorization header is

```
    $header = "AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)"
```

Comment: I added this answer to a list of workarounds I have found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64068150/134761

Answer (score 3):

After making git submodule relative path it worked

```
url= ../foo-dev-common
```

instead of

```
url=https://MY_ORG@dev.azure.com/MY_ORG/PInC/_git/foo-dev-common
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Still throws error: remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier Project123 does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.